# lattice points in a circle with radius r and origin (x,y)

Tags: integer-programming, integer-lattices

I have to write a code to calculate the number of integer lattice points inside a circle, and the radius and origin points must be entered by the user. I haven't been able to figure out the equation to this problem.

How do you calculate the number of integer lattice points in a circle of radius r and origin points (x,y)? Both values may not necessarily be integers.

Comment: There is no formula. You just pick them one by one and keep the count.

Comment: You can save some time by counting those in some inscribed square or inscribed ractangle inside your circle. For those closer to the edges, it may be harder.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the case when center does not have integer co-ordinates. But if it does, there a couple of ways we can attack the problem.

First, we can move the center to the origin without affecting the number of lattice points on or inside the circle. Then we can use the formulae given in [Gauss's Circle problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssCircleProblem.html). The time complexity is of course $O(r)$.

The second way would be to use the sum $r(n)$ , [the sum of squares function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html), given in the same page quoted above. As $r(n)$ has a simple Dirichlet convolution, we can use Dirichlet Hyperbola method. But still, the time complexity remains $O(r)$.

Third, is to use the algorithm I've described in my blog post, [Sublinear algorithm for Gauss's Circle Problem](http://am-just-a-nobody.blogspot.in/2018/02/a-sub-linear-algorithm-for-gausss.html). The post also leads to iterative and recursive versions of the python code I wrote for the problem. I believe its something like $O(r^{4/7})$ or $O(r^{1/2+\epsilon})$.

I calculated $N(10^{9})$ and $N(10^{10})$ using the code. From there on, the timing increases steadily but the bigger issue is the use of square roots in my code. A better programmer could get around this I think but I simply did not want to put any more time.

Finally, I've seen atleast one code with a similar idea which only uses integer arithmetic and pretty much uses the same algorithm like the one in my post. They both have the same run time, differing by atmost five seconds, for the $N(10^{10})$ case. Unfortunately, the forum where the code is available is not open to all.

Hope this helps.